# What exactly is a java call

Tags: java, call

this may be a a silly question, but I'm going through an old exam paper for revision and there is a question.

> *Write appropriate Java calls for the following Methods:*
>
> *`(a) public void sendMessage(){}`*
>
> *`(b) public void mergeWords(String word1, String Word2){}`*

This question is slightly confusing me as i believe a java call to simply be calling the method eg. under the `main(String[]args){ sentMessage() }` , this would be the method call,

and `mergeWords(word1,word2){ return word1+word2; }`

Can I get other opinions on this, please note this is only revision from a past paper.

Comment: I believe the "call" is the actual usage of the method..

Comment: Write some code that invokes the methods shown.

Comment: Hah, touching on the call vs invoke debate that rages. As I understand it you, to "invoke" requires an "invocant", a class or object. Ex: Object.getClass(). While a "call" just refers to simple function or subroutine call. Simply "sendMessage()" in your case. This debate get pretty lengthy esp in diff langs, checkout this discussion here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59045/call-vs-invoke-informatics-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calls can be made by writing the function name to be called following with the parameters with brackets. if the call is made to a void function then there should be a semicolon else you can either put a  semicolon at the end or use the return for any purpose.

e.g-
your answer (a) is

```
    sendMessage();
```

and (b) is

```
    mergeWords(word1,word2);
```

Comment: Thats what i thought, but seems too easy for an exam question, ill ask my lecturer and come back. Thanks

Comment: select this as your answer... if your professor says it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The call is the invocation of a method by a client.

```
public class Hello {
    // This is the definition of the method sayHello
    private static void sayHello( String name ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello, " + name );
    }

    public static final void main( String[] args ) {
        // This is the call to the method sayHello
        sayHello( "Robert" );
    }
}
```

So for your example, the calls are like

```
sendMessage();
mergeWords( "hello", "Robert" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Its just calling the other methods from the main one. Your sendMessage call is correct, `sendMessage();`  but the `mergeWords` call is : `mergeWords(String1, String2)`, where the strings represent string variables in the main method

Comment: Add a semicolon after `mergeWords(...)`, for consistency

Answer (score 0):

`under the main(String[]args){ sentMessage() } , this would be the method call,`

It won't be, because this are instance methods (non-static) so you need an instance to call/use them:

```
MyObject x = new MyObject();
x.sendMessage();
```

Comment: Thanks peter, altho it does not saying anything about using a class to call. i did think of this answer

Comment: It is not necessary to `saying anything about using a class to call`. The method declaration forces the user to create an instance.